# Switch to external display with shortcut instead of mouse on a Mac

Tags: mac, external-display

I want to switch to my external display via shortcut and not by moving my cursor to the other screen.

Comment: Need some more information for why this is needed and some clarification. You currently have a dual display and instead of manually moving the mouse to a window and making it active, you want to "tab" to it with the keyboard?

Comment: Why do I need this? Probably only for personal preference. I have two displays, one from my macbook pro and one extern hp monitor. And yes, instead of manually moving the mouse outside the one display into the other one I want to make the other window active by some kind of shortcut.

Answer (score 4):

The best thing to do for this case is to create a Keyboard Shortcut to switch desktops. To do this, you can do the following:

System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts

From this menu, select Mission Control on the left hand side, and at the bottom of this list, you should see an option for "Switch to Desktop #." This is the screen where you can create a keyboard shortcut in order to change focus between your desktops.

Comment: Is there a way to disable that the mouse can move out of the window?

Comment: This I am not sure of - I don't believe there is a way to restrict mouse movement to only the focused windows. If there is, there may be a 3rd party application for this, but not build in